# Preventing access to Dynamic Data tables programmatically

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, dynamic-data

I have an admin section for many databases set up using Dynamic Data.  When the user logs in, they are presented with a list of databases that they have access to modify (this list is kept in a separate database that is tied to the person's login information and also lists the tables they are allowed to see).  Upon clicking on the database, a list of tables is then shown in a second gridview on the same default.aspx page for the Dynamic Data site.

I have found a way to limit the tables shown to the ones corresponding to the database entries of allowed tables, however, upon viewing the table entries, any foreign key associations to tables they do not have access to show up with the dynamic data hyperlinks that take you over to those tables directly.

Soooo, if you are still with me, thank you.  <strike>My thought was to do a check in the global.asax file where the metamodels are bound and just not scaffold the tables that are supposed to be inaccessible.  Can this be done programmatically?  I would post some code but I'm not really sure what would be needed.  Here is where I'm thinking I can make an edit:</strike>

```
foreach (var table in metaModel.Value.Tables)
                    {
                        var tablePermission = authorizedTables.Any(p => p == table.Name);
                        if (tablePermission) continue;

                        //Next lines are possible ways in?
                        var canThisBeSetSomehow = table.Attributes.OfType<ScaffoldTableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
                        table.Scaffold = false;
                    }
```

Assume that "authorizedTables" is a string[] that holds my table names in the above scenario.  Is there a way to take the metamodel and edit it so that the remaining tables are inaccessible on a per user basis?